# Is $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$ when $f(x)=O(x^2), x\to 0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$ function on  $(-1,1)$. Assume $f(x)=O(x^2), x\to 0$.

My question: Is $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ $\mathscr{C}^{\infty}$ on $(-1,1)$? If not,  can someone give me a counter example?

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks a lot.